# Is `vm.swapiness=0` equivalent to `swapoff -a` (in kernel >= 3.5)

Tags: linux, swap, sysctl

Is setting in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
vm.swappiness=0
```

equivalent (except that it's persistent) to running `swapoff -a`, *in Linux kernels >= 3.5?

---

*[in earlier kernel versions, `0` meant 'no swapping until out of memory'](https://askubuntu.com/a/103916).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

[swapoff -a](https://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/8/swapoff/) completely turns off swapping.
[swappiness=0](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) tells the kernel to avoid swapping processes out of physical memory *for as long as possible*