# On AlmaLinux 8 or CentOS 7, does vm.swappiness=0 mean that Swap is fully disabled?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, swap, ram, alma-linux

I've been having an issue for many years where I have `vm.swappiness=1` in sysctl.conf, but even though there's plenty of RAM available (possibly almost full in terms of cached, although still 4GB free usually, but "available" is still quite free), swap keeps getting used all the time and sometimes almost full.

I simply don't want swap to be used at all, unless **absolutely necessary**.

I've just read [in this answer from 2019](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516844/95772) that:

> swappiness=0 tells the kernel to avoid swapping processes out of physical memory for as long as possible

However, I also read [in this answer from 2012](https://askubuntu.com/a/103916/361682) that:

> swappiness=0:
>
> - Kernel version 3.5 and newer: disables swapiness.
> - Kernel version older than 3.5: avoids swapping processes out of physical memory for as long as possible.

So I'm confused... does `vm.swappiness=0` fully disable swap, or is swap still used when absolutely necessary?

Kernel versions of my servers:

- 4.18 (AlmaLinux 8)
- 3.10 (CentOS 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to fully disable swap is to not set it up in the first place.

Setting `vm.swappiness` to 0 will cause the kernel to only use swap as a last resort; [it is currently documented as](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html#swappiness)

> At 0, the kernel will not initiate swap until the amount of free and file-backed pages is less than the high watermark in a zone.

As far as I’m aware, setting `swappiness` to 0 has never disabled swap entirely, so you’ll see swap used in both your environments if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It does not fully disable swap, at least not in the manner you may be thinking about. If you hibernate your system, it will use swap. When you resurrect the system, you may find that some swap is still in use. I found that out a couple of days ago. I had `swappiness` set to `0` with no swap used, and when I resurrected my system, I found that swap is still using 512K. This is on `5.14.21`.